# My Tab changed to 1st tab on screen rotation

Tags: android, rotation, tabactivity, screen-rotation

I am creating an android application, where a tabActivity resides.

the on create method of my tab activity is given below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);      
    setContentView(R.layout.logged);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_background);
    mytab=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    Log.e("id",mytab.getId()+"");
    mytab.setup();  
    setupTab( "AAAA","AAAA.class",tabImages[2]);
    setupTab( "BBBB","BBBB.class",tabImages[1]);
    setupTab("CCCC","CCCC.class",tabImages[0]);
    setupTab("DDDD","DDDD.class",tabImages[3]);
    setupTab("EEEE","EEEE.class",tabImages[4]);
}
```

and by searching some questions i got some idea that is adding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`  and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.
the code for these two functions is given below.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("tab_id",current_tab);
    Log.e("tab",""+savedInstanceState.getInt("tab_id"));
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mytab.setCurrentTab(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab_id"));
    Log.e("tab",""+savedInstanceState.getInt("tab_id"));
}
```

but it doesn't shows the current tab. it shows my default tab tab(0).. can u help me . is there  anything else to add in my code.

Comment: Your Activity gets destroyed and recreated when a configuration change happens, like a screen rotation. Thus, you should restore in onCreate(). See Sajmon's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move

```
mytab.setCurrentTab(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab_id"));
```

Into **onCreate()** method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
   // intialising and setup TabHost
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      mytab.setCurrentTab(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab_id"));
   }
}
```

Now it should works.